# fatal error: openssl/openssl.h: no such file or directory при компиляции ядра

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, kernel

При компиляции ядра в ubuntu выскакивает эта ошибка. openssl установлен и обновлен, не пойму в чем проблема.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стопицотмиллионный раз: используйте аккаунт с идентификатором 0 (в unix-подобных операционных системах обычно с этим идентификатором создаётся пользователь с именем root) только для выполнения задач по администрированию системы. это относится к всем способам авторизации: login, xsession, su, sudo, kexec и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: очевидно не хватает пакета devel или dev.